# Add Correct answers to Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Please help. I want to display the correct answers in an alert dialog, if i type "rightAnswers" inside "builder.setMessage("Answer : " + rightAnswers);" an alert show "Answer: 1". Number 1 instead of the correct answer. please teach me what to put to be able to display the correct answer. thank you so much.

```
public class thisactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button choice1,choice2;
ImageView images;
List<Model> list;
int turn = 1;
int rightAnswers = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_thisactivity);


    images = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);
    choice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    choice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < new Signsdatabase().answers.length; i++) {
        list.add(new Model(new Signsdatabase().answers[i], new 
         Signsdatabase().signs[i]));
    }

    newQuestion(turn);

    choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String alertTitle;              
   if(choice1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 
    1).getName())) {
                rightAnswers = rightAnswers + 1;
                alertTitle = "Correct!";
                if (turn < list.size()) {
                    turn++;
                    newQuestion(turn);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(thisactivity.this, "You have completed the Quiz!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
           AlertDialog.Builder(thisactivity.this)
            builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
            builder.setMessage("Answer : " + **CORRECT ANSWERS**); <---I WANT TO DISPLAY THE CORRECT ANSWER HERE BUT I DO NOT KNOW HOW------->
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.pic);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
    choice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (choice2.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(turn - 1).getName())) {
                rightAnswers = rightAnswers + 1;
                    if (turn < list.size()) {
                    turn++;
                    newQuestion(turn);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(thisactivity.this, "You have completed the Quiz!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getResults();
                }
            } else {


            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
           AlertDialog.Builder(Roadsigns.this)
            builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
            builder.setMessage("Answer : " + **CORRECT ANSWERS**); <---I WANT TO DISPLAY THE CORRECT ANSWER HERE BUT I DO NOT KNOW HOW------->
            builder.setIcon(R.drawable.pic);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                }
            });
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.show();

        }
    });
}
  ............
```

And this is my Signsdatabase

```
public class Signsdatabase {

Integer[] signs ={
        R.drawable.q1,
        R.drawable.q2,
        R.drawable.q3,
        };
 String[] answers = {
        "Ans1",
        "Ans2",
        "Ans3",
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You display the index of the right answer, you need to get the item from the list at the corresponding position:

```
builder.setMessage("Answer : " + signsdatabase.answers[rightAnswers]);
```

builder.setMessage("Answer : " + list[rightAnswers]);// it also check.

And you also need to initialize signsdatabase before

```
signsdatabase = new Signsdatabase();
```

Comment: the answer shown is always the first one ("Ans1"). anyway thank you for answering

Comment: I tried this but the answer that shows up is for the next question "builder.setMessage("Answer :" + choice1.getText().toString()); "

Answer (score 0):

Make this change in alter dialog.

make Signsdatabase object or make static in answer array.

```
  builder.setMessage("Answer : " + Signsdatabase.answers[rightAnswers]);
```

Comment: I tried this but the answer that shows up is for the next question "builder.setMessage("Answer :" + choice1.getText().toString()); "

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the correct index of the answer You can do one of the following :

**One**

Create an object of SignsDatabase :

```
signsDb = new Signsdatabase();
```

With index *i* of correct answer :

```
builder.setMessage("Answer : "+ signDb.answers[i];
```

**Two**

If you do not want to create an instance of SignDatabase, you can declare the answers as static variable so :

```
public class SignDatabase{
... //some code here

public static String[] answers = ["Abc","xyz"];

}
```

Then access it directly by calling :

```
builder.setMessage(SignDatabase.answers[i]);
```

Comment: tried this but the answer show is always the first answer in the list, thanks for answering

Comment: I tried this but the answer that shows up is for the next question "builder.setMessage("Answer :" + choice1.getText().toString()); "